# Nagios client tcp connection to Nagios Server using NSCA, how to make this connection stay up forever

Tags: nagios

I have setup a nagios distributed monitoring system environment and i am able to send passive checks to Nagios server using send_nsca. When i look at the handshake between Nagios Client and Nagios Server, i see that Nagios Client is establishing a tcp connection to Nagios server whenever it has something to send and terminating the connection once the client is done sending the information. I want the tcp connection to stay up forever instead of terminating every time after data transfer is done. Could anyone please let me the know the process to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without modifying the standard NSCA daemon.  Normally, it will time out and that's why the NSCA client reestablishes the connection.

I've implemented send_nsca in both Perl and Ruby, and in both cases cannot make a persistent connection work.

A better solution, though, if you are using Nagios 3.x is to install the [livestatus](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_livestatus.html) module (part of check_mk).  This allows passive checks to be submitted, but supports a persistent connection and a whole lot more.  We've moved to using this instead for many cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve for your reply, and i am looking into a solution where i can centrally modify the configuration files of distributed nagios systems. How do you handle managing the nagios systems centrally? I appreciate your assistance. Thank you

Comment: We use mod_gearman on the central Nagios server, so the satellites do not actually run Nagios at all, only the individual check commands.  These feed back to the central collector via gearman.

We used to use multiple Nagios servers but it became very difficult to maintain (we used a custom in-house script to split the configuration up and push it out)